# Download Pdf file in react native using post request in fetch

Tags: react-native, expo

How to download a pdf file using post request in react native,

Answer (score 1):

You can use rn-fetch-blob to download or store the any type of file in local storage .

follow this link for more

> https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob

it's help me.

Answer (score 0):

With expo if you have file url after post :

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

FileSystem.downloadAsync(
   DOWNLOAD_PDF_URL,
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + ‘downloadedfile.pdf’
   )
    .then(({ uri, status }) => {

   })
```

Comment: Without Expo. ?

Comment: Thank you for responding me,can u give me a full code for this, Actually my requirement is  in post method i have to send data, then file will be downloaded, how can i do that